# SSH deny rule is allowing me to SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, vpc

I am learning AWS VPC where I am assigning NACL Inbound/Outbound Rules as below: Right now i am doing for All IPs

```
Inbound
Rule #    Type           Allow/Deny
100       All Traffic    Allow
200       SSH            Deny
 *        All Traffic    Deny


Outbound
Rule #    Type           Allow/Deny
100       SSH            Deny
200       All Traffic    Allow
 *        All Traffic    Deny
```

I am wondering how my SSH is working as rule says lower number will be evaluated first, and in outbound rule i have denied SSH. Can anyone explain how the rule actually works in AWS?

Comment: did you restart the sshd service?

Comment: yes, then also it is working

Comment: Ok, to me it does not make much sense. What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to deny all in- and outbound traffic or do you only want to deny SSH?

Comment: deny only ssh traffic

Comment: In the begining I would deny anything. And open up the ports you need then.

`Inbound
* All Traffic Deny

Outbound
* All Traffic Deny`

Comment: How this actually works?  I need that answer.. I dont need a solution here man

Comment: At first place you allow all inbound traffic - which also includes SSH. When you connect with your client it chooses for example port 12345 as source port to connect to the servers destination port 22. The server will try to send traffic from it's port 22 to the client on port 12345 - so you deny the outbound 22 which is in that case not used - but the 12345 port is used to the client (which is allowed because of the rule 200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does not make much sense to me to open all ports on your server. I would try this approach and add for example the ports you need in order - here 443 (if needed) :

```
Inbound
Rule #    Type         Allow/Deny
100       443          Allow
*         All Traffic  Deny

Outbound
Rule #    Type         Allow/Deny
100       443          Allow
*         All Traffic  Deny
```

But be aware that the ACL in AWS is a stateless firewall. Every request (inbound or outbound) is treated   as independent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, it is recommended that you **leave the NACLs at their default settings** (allow all). They should only be used for subnet-level security, such as creating DMZs.

**Security Groups** should normally be used to control access on ports. Security Groups are stateful, which makes things easier too.